# persistent counter in Ruby/Rails for each

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, each, counter

I have the following code that gives me a bunch of locations and an index for each location.

```
<%= paginate @locations %>

<% @locations.each_with_index do |location, index| %>
  <h1><%= index + 1 %></h1>
  <h2><%= location.name %></h2>
<% end %>
```

Everything works fine, I get all the elements in the right order with the right index (palace hast the most visits, then bar, etc.):

- 1 Palace
- 2 Bar
- 3 Cinema
- 4 Restaurant
- 5 Ballon

I use Kaminari for pagination and if I klick on the second page to show the next 5 locations, the index starts again at 1, but it should give me 6.

- next page (should continue the index with 6)
- 1 Arena (should be 6)
- 2 Stadion (should be 7)
- and so on ...

So how do I get a persistent counter/index which continues on the next page?

Thanks in advance

**Update**

I came up with the following, works great so far:

```
<% if params[:page].nil? || params[:page] == "0" || params[:page] == "1" %>
  <% x = 0 %>
<% else %>
  <% page = params[:page].to_i - 1 %>
  <% x = page * 10 %>
<% end %>

<% @locations.each_with_index do |location, index| %>
  <%= index + x + 1 %>
  ...
```

Comment: Could you just use the id of the record? `<h1><%= location.id %></h1>`

Comment: no guarantee that the id will be consecutive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each_with_index  is a plain ruby method (Enumerable I think) that doesn't know anything about the pagination structure.  You may have to provide a additional calculation, unless Kaminari provides something (I haven't use Kaminari yet)

If this were will_paginate, I'd do something like this, and maybe it would work for you too:

```
<h1><%= index + 1 + ((params[:page] || 0 ) * @items_per_page )  %></h1>
```

(you have to set @items_per_page yourself)